# JAVA: Not sure about getting constructor with generic types in reflection

Tags: java, reflection, generic-programming

```java
public class A<T, U> implements S<T, U> {
    private final T first;
    private final U second;

    public A(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to call the public constructor from reflection?

What I'm trying to do is

```java
classLoader.loadClass("A").getConstructor(<Something Here>).newInstance()
```

Is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: If constructor is public why you want to use reflection?

Comment: As the generics information is more or less lost at runtime (type-erasure) it should be `getConstructor(Object.class, Object.class)`

Comment: @mslowiak I'm using this thing from Minecraft Project, where Class differs every time the version changes. I want to create a version independent project, so I need a method to call the class without directly calling.

Comment: @dpr I'll try with the Object.class thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since type parameters are erased, instead of passing in the fictional `T.class` and `U.class` (which doesn't mean anything), you should just pass in two `Object.class`, because that is what `T` and `U` erase to:

```
A.class.getConstructor(Object.class, Object.class)
```

You should also pass some parameters to `newInstance`. For example, to create a `A<Integer, String>`, you could do:

```
A<Integer, String> a = 
    (A<Integer , String>)A.class.getConstructor(Object.class, Object.class)
    .newInstance(1, "Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1):

The type parameters T and U are *erased* and become `Object` when the code is compiled. So use `Object.class` to indicate the constructor parameter types.

```
Constructor aConstructor = aClass.getConstructor(Object.class, Object.class);
```